# Terminal Password Management?

Tags: command-line, password, gnome-terminal

I've been using my Macbook Air through the pandemic and I've been impressed with iTerm2's password management.  You can define regex watch strings in the terminal and it will pop up a menu from an unlocked encrypted password store that you can quickly type short character shortcuts to paste in the proper enormous password.  Now that I'm back to my Ubuntu desktop, I'm wondering is there anything like this for Gnome Terminal, another terminal or Linux in general?

Answer (score 0):

Alacritty has ["regex hints"](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/blob/master/docs/features.md#hints), that watch the buffer for a match allowing for the general case to act on it or launch something externally.

You can combine it with the dmenu `passmenu` helper inside the `pass` util or something that access the gnome-keyring (`secret-tool`, [keyman](https://github.com/dpoetzsch/keyman), [gnome-keyring-cli](https://github.com/drafnel/gnome-keyring-cli)) or any password manager that surfaces a search option.

The default regex in the [alacritty.yml](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/blob/96fc9ecc9a62c8a766da745d05fbe60e6c2e1efe/alacritty.yml#L448) contains a url example and explains how to use the regex match text as input.

Tangentially: wherever there is interactive terminal input of credentials I usually find a way to use the utils preferred way to read out a secret from the filesystem (mysql/psql/mongo/ssh) or invoke a password cli util automatically (mutt/msmtp/fetchmail). There are ways to secure filepath secrets.